# Failed to transform artifact 'design.aar (com.android.support:design:28.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

I m building Android wear application but I have this error if I try to compile my application:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'design.aar (com.android.support:design:28.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
      > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\design\28.0.0\bef882d1796b085fa89a5f1cec42a8edd2351e6c\design-28.0.0.aar.
         > java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b1d8b4b40a44b6d16bbcc853f378a37d\design-28.0.0\jars\classes.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medicinanucleare.cardio"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-bluetooth:1.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.so', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    implementation('com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps')
    }
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.7.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-bluetooth:1.7'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math:2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:0.26'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

    //Job Scheduler and MQTT
    implementation 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Fcm Integeration
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'


    implementation files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')

    implementation 'com.idevicesinc:sweetblue:4.0.0@aar'

    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
}


This is my AndroidManifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.firebasewatchapp">

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

  <uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"
      tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

  <uses-feature
      android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
      android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"
      android:required="true" />



  <application
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:name=".Global"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
      android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.RadioActiveAlertDialog" />
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="28.0.0" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".activities.VitalStatsActivity" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I fixed it?